flet. Помогите разобраться с поиском элементов на странице
У меня проблема с тем как получить нужный мне элемент на странице.
Я знаю такой способ например:
page.controls[0] и далее обшаривать контролы с контентами проваливаясь всё глубже.
Мне не очень нравится опираться на порядкоый номер.
Можно конечно фильтрами обмазаться, но эт если нет выбора.
Главный вопрос, как правильно искать элемент на странице?
Подвопросы:

Я вот заметил что у всех элементов есть атрибут "key" у того же ft.Container например, для чего он нужен, может помочь в поисках?.
Вот у меня есть метод:

    def collapse(self, e: ft.ControlEvent):
        e.control.rotate.angle += pi
        e.page.update()


я нашел элемент(e.control ) который вызывает событие, можно относительно него двинутся на верх к родителю?

А вообще есть какой-то способ вывести в консоль типо карту проекта для удобства, или что то похожее где все элементы перечислены со вложенностью?

